# Battery mangement IC with USB C 2.0

Tags: power, batteries, battery-charging, usb-device, usb-c

I am currently designing a one-cell battery USB C 2.0 device. I saw many battery chargers from Texas Instruments such as bq24295, bq25628, bq25898, bq25890/2, bq25601, etc.

I would like to use and charge the peripheral in PC USB or charge the peripheral with USB Charger with boost. After reading numerous datasheets, I have a few questions:

Some ICs uses D+/D- lines for *"USB Host or Charging Port D+/D- Detection
Compatible to USB Battery Charger Spec (BC1.2)"*. Can I still use D+/D- for communications or should I select an IC without D+/D-? If I select the first, what is the right way to connect it? If I select the latter, has the IC battery boost charge?

Thank you!

Comment: USB-C has its own mechanism for controlling power delivery, so for a new design you should use that instead.

Comment: @Finbarr. Thank you! Yeah, I'm reading that at now, with USB C, cc lines are used to this, but, just out of curiosity. How is to implement with old protocols using data lines?

Comment: USB-C does not put any voltage on Vbus until you activate it using the CC lines while USB-A always has 5V present on Vbus. The two mechanisms are pretty much incompatible.